# Roaming settings not working in the outlook App

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

I am using the roaming setting in my outlook add-in to store the oAuth and other information of my app. The add-in is working fine in the outlook browser but it is not working in the outlook app. can anybody suggest if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

There are two universal steps I start from:

1. Try clearing the Office cache on your computer. See [For Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-development-errors#for-windows).
2. [Debug your add-in with runtime logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging)

You can read more about possible cases in the [Troubleshoot development errors with Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-development-errors#add-in-doesnt-work-on-edge-but-it-works-on-other-browsers) article.